# How to check if a shortcode (including its params) exist?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Is there a way to check if a shortcode exist, including its 'id' attribute ?
For example, checking if the following shortcode is active on the website: [shortcode id="3268"]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try var_dump on the attributes within the Shortcode.

```html
// var dump to show shortcode attributes are working
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $att = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    var_dump($att);
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

When you call the Shortcode ( [bartag] ) in this example - you will see the attributes default values (or the values you add to the Shortcode).

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a shortcode API [shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) in wordpress, allowing you to call functions and perform actions when the shortcode is present while displaying the page. If you want to check an entire website, you will have to code a plugin that goes thru all the content.

Comment: Thanks Manu, I know that already, I'd like to check if a full shortcode (including its params) is registered within the WP database.